# Hue cannot load Presto Schema dbc does not exist

Tags: sql, jdbc, hue, presto

I just built Hue-4.1.0 and it's able to execute Presto sql via jdbc. Here is my hue-presto config:

```
[notebook]
  [[interpreters]]
    [[[presto-jdbc]]]
      name=Presto-jdbc
      interface=jdbc
      options='{"url": "jdbc:presto://localhost:18080/platform_data/platform_data", "driver": "com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver", "user": "analysis"}'
      # Doesn't work either
      # options='{"url": "jdbc:presto://localhost:18080/platform_data/", "driver": "com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver", "user": "analysis"}'
```

Query Presto is OK but when I click the refresh button see pic:[reflash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50frH.jpg), I got this:

> An error occurred while calling o237.execute. : java.sql.SQLException: Query failed (#20180605_105344_00147_ugf87): line 1:26: Schema dbc does not exist at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoResultSet.resultsException(PrestoResultSet.java:1798) at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoResultSet.getColumns(PrestoResultSet.java:1742) at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoResultSet.(PrestoResultSet.java:118) at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoStatement.internalExecute(PrestoStatement.java:246) at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoStatement.execute(PrestoStatement.java:225) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231) at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381) at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259) at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133) at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.SemanticException: line 1:26: Schema dbc does not exist at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.visitTable(StatementAnalyzer.java:845) at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.visitTable(StatementAnalyzer.java:258) at com.facebook.presto.sql.tree.Table.accept(Table.java:53) at com.facebook.presto.sql.tree.AstVisitor.process(AstVisitor.java:27) at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.process(StatementAnalyzer.java:270) at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.analyzeFrom(StatementAnalyzer.java:1919) at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.visitQuerySpecification(StatementAnalyzer.java:957) at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.visitQuerySpecification(StatementAnalyzer.java:258) at com.facebook.presto.sql.tree.QuerySpecification.accept(QuerySpecification.java:127) at com.facebook.presto.sql.tree.AstVisitor.process(AstVisitor.java:27) at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.process(StatementAnalyzer.java:270) at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.process(StatementAnalyzer.java:280) at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.visitQuery(StatementAnalyzer.java:676) at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.visitQuery(StatementAnalyzer.java:258) at com.facebook.presto.sql.tree.Query.accept(Query.java:94) at com.facebook.presto.sql.tree.AstVisitor.process(AstVisitor.java:27) at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.process(StatementAnalyzer.java:270) at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer.analyze(StatementAnalyzer.java:244) at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:72) at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:64) at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlQueryExecution.(SqlQueryExecution.java:169) at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlQueryExecution$SqlQueryExecutionFactory.createQueryExecution(SqlQueryExecution.java:660) at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlQueryExecution$SqlQueryExecutionFactory.createQueryExecution(SqlQueryExecution.java:582) at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlQueryManager.createQuery(SqlQueryManager.java:417) at com.facebook.presto.server.protocol.Query.(Query.java:186) at com.facebook.presto.server.protocol.Query.create(Query.java:153) at com.facebook.presto.server.protocol.StatementResource.createQuery(StatementResource.java:144) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor674.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:183) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277) at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272) at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268) at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316) at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298) at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268) at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703) at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416) at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370) at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389) at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342) at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655) at com.facebook.presto.server.security.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:69) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) at io.airlift.http.server.TraceTokenFilter.doFilter(TraceTokenFilter.java:64) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) at io.airlift.http.server.TimingFilter.doFilter(TimingFilter.java:52) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:674) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:169) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:61) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:755) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:673) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Some person got the same problem as well: 
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Web-UI-Hue-Beeswax/HUE-and-Presto-Integration-Error-on-Page-Load/td-p/62353

I am hoping for your help!

Comment: Please remove the pictures and put the stacktrace as text into your question. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to assume it's connected to a Teradata system, `dbc` is Teradata's metadata database.

Answer (score 0):

check this issue on GitHub: [JDBC connector only supports Teradata](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/issues/753).

seems it's been fixed in version `4.3.0`;

you could try using [`[librdbms]` section](http://cloudera.github.io/hue/latest/administrator/configuration/editor/#postgresql) also